# How to filter on multiple SubItems in ObjectListView

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, objectlistview

So, I am trying to programmatically add in a ModelFilter to my ObjectListView that will look at two (or more) columns and filters on each separately.  Currently, I think that ObjectListView only supports one filter, but I may be missing something in the code/documentation.

As an example, one of my intended filters is to look at column "Active" and that has values of "A" or "T".  Another column is a Supervisor Name.  So, I want to find all entries where Supervisor name = "Smith" and Active = "A".

I can get the filter to work for either of these options separately using TextMatchFilter, but cannot figure out how to get both to work at the same time.

The minor problem I see is that if the Supervisor Name contains an "A", then using the standard Filter will return the whole row.  I have been able to get around that by programmatically setting the Searchable property for columns to false if I don't want to look at them, and then turn them back on once the list is filtered.  However, I have a feeling that if I turn Searchable on for the Supervisor column, I will get the unwanted results.

Does anyone know of a way to get the filter to work on multiple columns, using only the indicated columns for each filter?

(I have no sample code to show that helps in solving this.  However, if you really want to see what I have for my filtering code, I will be happy to add that; it is in VB however).

Current Code - This looks at a value chosen by the user (searchMeth) and enables searching on that column.  It then does the search for what was entered in the txtSearch box.  However, in addition to this, I want to add in an additional filter for Supervisor. (See the AndAlso comment

```
    olvEmps.UseFiltering = True
    OlvColumn1.Searchable = False
    OlvColumn2.Searchable = False
    OlvColumn4.Searchable = False
    OlvColumn3.Searchable = False
    OlvColumn5.Searchable = False

    Select Case searchMeth
        Case "Name"
            OlvColumn1.Searchable = True
        Case "Employee Number"
            OlvColumn2.Searchable = True
        Case "Department"
            OlvColumn3.Searchable = True
    End Select

    olvEmps.OwnerDraw = True
    Dim tFilter As BrightIdeasSoftware.TextMatchFilter = BrightIdeasSoftware.TextMatchFilter.Contains(olvEmps, txtSearch.Text)
    'andalso olvColumn5 = supeName?

    olvEmps.ModelFilter = tFilter
    olvEmps.DefaultRenderer = New BrightIdeasSoftware.HighlightTextRenderer(tFilter)

    OlvColumn1.Searchable = True
    OlvColumn2.Searchable = True
    OlvColumn3.Searchable = True
    OlvColumn4.Searchable = True
    OlvColumn5.Searchable = True
```

Comment: Do add your filtering code so that it can get easier to help. =) No matter it is VB or C#, as long as you tag your question with the good language tag so the answerers will be able to provide you with assistance in the desired language whether it is VB or C#. =)

Comment: Code has been added and tags changed.  Thanks @Will

Comment: I'll see what I can do with your code sample. I hope it'll help! =)

Comment: I just edited my answer to provide you with further details based on your supplied code sample.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm sure the PredicateBuilder solution will work, but `ObjectListView` comes with a simpler solution already.

`TextMatchFilter` can be limited to which columns it searches via the `Columns` property. Set this to an array of columns that you want to consider.

```
TextMatchFilter filter1 = TextMatchFilter.Contains(olvEmps, txtSearch.Text)
filter1.Columns = new [] { this.olvColumn1, this.olvColumn2 };
```

You can combine two filters using the `CompositeAllFilter` to match two or more other filters.

```
this.olvEmps.ModelFilter = new CompositeAllFilter(new List<IModelFilter> { filter1, filter2 });
```

Comment: +1 how can you go past a native 3-line solution suggested by the creator of objectlistview himself?

Comment: This is great.  I will go and try this out as soon as possible.  Thanks.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thanks for the info (I told you I missed something in documentation), and thanks for the great control.

Answer (score 1):

Though I don't yet fully understand your deal, I'll give it a shot with the [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) that is part of the LINQKit assembly which you can download [here](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx).

As such, filtering on multiple columns shall get easy. Perhaps shall you consider to reset the binding of your `ObjectListView` control once your source collection has been filtered.

Grossly, I would do about the following:

1. Load your datum;
2. Display them through data binding;
3. Once a column is clicked for filter, make a call to your "Filter" method which will apply your predicates;
4. Rebind your control with the new filtered collection.

Please refer to the PredicateBuilder documentation at the link provided previously. Another example to building dynamic filters is illustrated here: "[How would this query translate into a dynamic Linq expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978174/how-would-this-query-translate-into-a-dynamic-linq-expression)" for a search engine I implemented.

In my case, the filters were applied directly against the database results. Aside, it can even be used in your situation with in-memory datum since it is Linq based.

I'm sure I'll be able to provide further assitance when you post your code sample for filtering the information.

> EDIT #1

After I have read the code sample provided, here's what I believe would do the trick. As for the Searchable property, I am no familiar of this approach, so maybe I can miss something important out of your code and if it is so, feel free to point me what I could have missed. =)

Note that I assume that all of your datum are string, since I am verifying whether your datum is null or white space. Furthermore, the way I see it, to filter a result set is to bring visible only records which meet certain criterion. You don't want to see what doesn't meet the criterion. It's the same as a WHERE clause in SQL.

```
public class FilterCriterion {
    public bool HasEmployeeName { get { return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(EmployeeName); } }
    public bool HasEmployeeNumber { get { return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(EmployeeNumber); } }
    public bool HasDepartment { get { return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Department); } }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
}
```

The FilterCriterion class shall be used to apply any filter that you want against your data source, collection or whatsoever.

```
var employees = LoadEmployeesFromUnderlyingDataStore();
var criterion = new FilterCriterion();

switch(searchMeth) {
    case "Name": filter.EmployeeName = "the name to filter by"; break;
    case "EmployeeNumber": filter.EmployeeNumber = "the number to filter by"; break;
    case "Department": filter.Department = "the department to filter by"; break;
}

var filter = PredicateBuilder.True<Employee>(); // assuming you have an employee class.
if (criterion.HasEmployeeName) 
    filter.And(e => e.Name.ContainsLike(criterion.EmployeeName));
if (criterion.HasEmployeeNumber)
    filter.And(e => e.EmployeeNumber.ContainsLike(criterion.EmployeeNumber));
if (criterion.HasDepartment)
    filter.And(e => e.Department.ContainsLike(criterion.Department));

var filteredEmployees = employees.Where(filter);

// Supply your ObjectListView the way you're used to and this shall function.
```

Aside, you could also, if you have to deal with such string variables write a `ContainsLike` extension method to the string class.

```
namespace System {
public static class StringExtensions {
    public static bool ContainsLike(this string input, string value) {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) return false;
        input = input.ToLower().RemoveDiacritics();
        value = value.ToLower().RemoveDiacritics();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) return false;
        return input.Contains(value);
    }
    public static string RemoveDiacritics(this string input) {
        return input == null ? null :      
                        Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding(1251).GetBytes(input));
    }
}
}
```

I do hope this helps, otherwise inform me of what I misunderstood from your question and we'll try to figure this out together.

Should you need the VB version of this code, I'll try to translate to the best of my VB knowledge.

This code is provided as is and has not been tested, except for both the string extension methods.

Comment: I will go check out the PredicateBuilder.  Unfortunately, I am not familiar with LINQ (yet), but based upon what I can understand of your solution above, it appears that I would have to add in some data binding?  Currently I use the SetObjects method of the ObjectListView using a collection of objects.  Plus, I do not expect the end user to click on a column to filter; I will be using Tile view, which doesn;t even supply column headers to do so.  I will let you know if the PredicateBuilder will do the trick though.

Comment: Oh, and I guess I could always use lambdas on my original collection and use the new filtered collection to populate the ObjectListView again.  This seems like a workaround however.

Comment: You can definitely use lambda expressions and the power of Linq to help you out. Please allow me some time so that I can figure out something for you and see if it'll help. =)